# Exit an infinite stream

Tags: flutter, dart

I've written this piece of code in order to scan Bluetooth devices in my Flutter app with the help of [flutter_blue](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_blue) package.

```
Stream<List<ScanResult>> scannedDevices(int durationSeconds) async* {
  Stream<List<ScanResult>> stream = _flutterBlue.scanResults;
  List<ScanResult> payload = List<ScanResult>.empty(growable: true);

  _flutterBlue.startScan(timeout: Duration(seconds: durationSeconds));

  await for (List<ScanResult> results in stream) {
    payload.clear();
    for (ScanResult result in results) {
      payload.add(result);
    }
    yield payload;
}
```

The problem is that `scanResults` Stream is infitnite (see [here](https://github.com/pauldemarco/flutter_blue/blob/master/lib/src/flutter_blue.dart#L46)) and because of that the `await for` loop runs foreverer, leaving my `scannedDevices` Stream running forever too.

Is there a way to break the `await for` loop after scanDuration has passed? Thanks

Comment: try using Completer, Refer a link for more info: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-async/Completer-class.html

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can simply return null for breaking loop

```
 Stream<List<ScanResult>> scannedDevices(int durationSeconds) 
  async* {
    Stream<List<ScanResult>> stream = _flutterBlue.scanResults;
     List<ScanResult> payload = List<ScanResult>.empty(growable: 
       true);

     _flutterBlue.startScan(timeout: Duration(seconds: 
 durationSeconds));

 await for (List<ScanResult> results in stream) {
   payload.clear();
   for (ScanResult result in results) {
  payload.add(result);
 }
return payload;
}
```

Comment: You cannot use return for returing values from Stream since it is async*

Answer (score 0):

Simply add an `timeout` to the stream that you are listening.

Another option is to use the `StreamTransformer` instead of what you did with `await for`.

```dart
Stream<List<ScanResult>> scannedDevices(int durationSeconds) async* {
  Stream<List<ScanResult>> stream = _flutterBlue.scanResults.timeout(Duration(seconds: durationSeconds));
  List<ScanResult> payload = List<ScanResult>.empty(growable: true);

  _flutterBlue.startScan(timeout: Duration(seconds: durationSeconds));

  await for (List<ScanResult> results in stream) {
      payload.clear();
      for (ScanResult result in results) {
        payload.add(result);
      }
      yield payload;
  }
}
```

Comment: I have already tried .timeout method but I get this exception each time `Unhandled Exception: TimeoutException after 0:00:02.000000: No stream event`

Comment: How should I implement the `StreamTransformer` in this scenario?

Comment: I was reviewing the code and I didn't get the proposal of it, by my see you don't need this payload, because your only proposal of this function is to call the `startScan` and return the stream of it. I'm correct?
Because if it is what I'm thinking, we can remove the `payload` and the `await for`, and finally only return the `stream` using on the last line a `yield* stream;`. Or removing the `async*` from the function and just return the stream using `return`.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I'm actually filtering the Bluetooth devices inside that second `for` loop, I didn't include it here just to make it simpler.